# Is there a way to synchronize two workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a workbook in Excel, where there are some "front-end" sheets and "database" sheets. So I want to track if any change to the "database" sheet was made, and if so, make the same change to the workbook, which is uploaded on a Google Drive. As well as, when the local workbook is opened, it first checks if any changes to the Google Drive "database" was made and if so, it first gets the changes and refreshes the local "database" sheets.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Is there an efficient way to do it using vba macros? I could think off few ways to export data to google docs, but I have no idea how to check if there were data change on the drive and import it if so.

Comment: VBA is definitely not the best language to design server-client architectures, but yes it is feasible. You will though face a lot of problems that are typical of shared-DB applications, for example: user A opens workbook Z and modifies it, user B does the same, how will you handle the conflicts when they both save it? If your question is just "is there a way to sync a Google Drive sheet in Excel" the answer is yes, it is feasible, if you search those keywords on Google you will find many results.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ So I was thinking of recording date and time of any change as a variable. Then compare that variable to the last modified date and time of the worksheet on google drive. So if it is > then export data to google drive, if < then before any change to the local data base could be made, first import data from the google drive and then save you changes to the local database and then transfer data to the google drive.